# Constrain object rotation to behave like joystick

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to constrain an object's rotation, so that it behaves like a joystick (meaning it can only rotate up to some maximum angle from center).

I tried to constrain rotation on each individual axis, but they behaved really weirdly when rotating (the angle values didn't just grow linearly). The input I'm using to supply this rotation is the rotation of physical controller. How can I do this?

This is how it works now and how I want it to work:
[image: rotation]
Images are 2D but it applies to all axes.

Comment: I don't think you've supplied quite enough information here for users to help out. Do you have images of the properties of the object you're manipulating, possibly code too? Visual aids demonstrating what you want to achieve could be helpful too, along with details explaining what you mean by "they behave really weird when rotating" (eg. How the present behaviour fails to accomplish what you want.)

Comment: The object I'm manipulating isn't important, this problem could be applied to any object with rotation. I don't have code either because I simply don't have any idea yet, but I'm gonna add some images.

Comment: To clarify, how are you receiving the input that will manipulate the virtual joystick? Are you using `Input.GetAxis()` to get values from an actual joystick (values ranging from [-1, 1]), or is the data in some other form?

Comment: No, I'm receiving rotation(quaternion), and right now I just set localRotation to this quaternion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like there are two parts to the problem:

1. Determine whether supplied rotation exceeds maximum allowable rotation of object
2. If the supplied rotation is too large, reducing that rotation so it fits within the rotational constraints, then applying it

*In my code examples, I'll be assuming that the initial rotation of the virtual joystick is zero across the board (`Quaternion.identity`), and that your supplied rotation is called `newRotation`.*

For the first part, [`Quaternion.Angle()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Angle.html) comes to mind. This gives the angle between two given rotations, and can be used like so:

```cs
if (Quaternion.Angle(Quaternion.identity, newRotation) < 30){
    // Angle from initial to new rotation is under 30 degrees
}
```

For the second part, you'll need some way of reducing the supplied rotation so it is within the allowable angle from the initial rotation. For that, [`Quaternion.Slerp()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) is useful. This allows you to interpolate between two rotations, returning a `Quaternion` that is a combination of the two supplied. For example, this gives back half of `newRotation`:

```cs
Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion.identity, newRotation, 0.5f);
```

Putting these two methods together, you can write a clamping method which ensures that the supplied rotation never exceeds a certain angle from the initial rotation. Here's an example usage:

```cs
// Maximum angle joystick can tilt at
public float tiltAngle;
// If this isn't your initial rotation, set it in Awake() or Start()
Quaternion initialRotation = Quaternion.identity;

void Update(){
    Quaternion newRotation = MethodToGetSuppliedRotation();
    Quaternion clampedRotation = ClampRotation(initialRotation, newRotation, tiltAngle);
    transform.localRotation = clampedRotation;
}

// Clamps "b" such that it never exceeds "maxAngle" degrees from "a"
Quaternion ClampRotation(Quaternion a, Quaternion b, float maxAngle){
    float newAngle = Quaternion.Angle(a, b);
    if (newAngle <= maxAngle){
        // Rotation within allowable constraint
        return b;
    }
    else{
        // This is the proportion of the new rotation that is within the constraint
        float angleRatio = maxAngle / newAngle;
        return Quaternion.Slerp(a, b, angleRatio);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out as soon as I go back to home.